# Data transfer rates differing due to file size?

Tags: networking, file-transfer

Today I was testing out my new 1Gbps network switch when I realized that the data transfer rates were different from file to file.

First I tried to get a 3,86GB file from my NAS and I got about 49,4MBps.

Then, I tried to transfer a much lighter file (812MB) and I got about 113MBps.

The point of this question is: Why is the DTR lower when the file is heavier and higher when the file is lighter?

**NOTE1:** Tried to post this question at [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/data-transfer-rates-differing-due-to-file-size) but got told that I should post it here instead.

**NOTE2:** I'm using a TP-link TL-SG105 as my network switch between my NAS and my PC.

**NOTE3:** Due to not have enough reputation, you can find screenshots on the original post [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/data-transfer-rates-differing-due-to-file-size).

**Edits**: I did not use any measure tools to get these values. Just Windows explorer copying a file from a network drive. I know that it isn't accurate but still, is a big gap.

Connection over cat6 ethernet cable and the runs do not exceed the maximum length for gigabit.

Comment: What are your measuring tools and procedures exactly? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: How fast can you read the files from your local storage drive (ignoring it afterwards, something like `dd if=file of=/dev/null`) Are the files already compressed, maybe one already is and the other is very compressible through the transfer, increasing it's apparent speed

Comment: How much RAM does your NAS have, and how fast its disks are? Sounds a bit like the small file was already cached entirely in RAM during your test.

Comment: @grawity my NAS is an Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 with 2x2GB DDR2 667 + ~10GB swap, an Intel Pentium Dual E2200 2.20GHz and a 1TB Seagate HDD 7200RPM.

Comment: There are your problems - 1x Seagate HDD.  You may be able to get better performance if you change it to RAID1.  Another thing to try is running vmstat 2 on the NAs while doing the copy and see if the NAS is bottlenecking and where.  If it is paging swap you may want to set vm.swappiness to a low number (like 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At files of those sizes the issue is less likely to be related to file sizes (as may be the case for very small files).

The most likely issue is that your NAS is simply not delivering the file fast enough, possibly due to disk fragmentation and location on hard drive.   A typical hard disk maxes out at about 110 megabytes per second, with the outside tracks being about twice as fast as the inside ones.

Another significant issue is the connection between the NAS, PC and router.  If the NAS and PC are gigabit connections, and connected to the router in a typical home user setup, data needs to go from the NAS to the PC, and then from the PC to the router.  A Gigabit connection maxes out at 125 megabytes per second, and other people using the Internet through the router (even intermittently) at the same time will impact speed - especially of a single threaded connection.

Another possible problem is WIFI interference - if one or both of the connections were done over WIFI at different times, that could greatly impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just edited my question to specify the kind of runs I deployed in my house (cat6). I was not using WIFI and the connection is NAS -> Gigabit Switch -> PC. The only cables attached to this switch were the NAS, My PC, and another cable from my main 10/100 switch. The hard drive is a Seagate 1TB 7200RPM.